# Camera render overwrites material color

Tags: rendering, materials, camera

I have placed a camera with the following world properties

[image]

The scene looks as following
[image]

Now when I try to render, all I get is
[image]

And that is of course what I do not want. I simply want the colors to appear as they are given and that the blue is merely the background (such that I can easily remove it in Photoshop for a transparent image). I've also tried without placing a spot light but to no avail.

Comment: Could you please add your blender file? It would be helpful to work with it. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph: Do you know that Blender can render a transparent background (*Render Properties > Film > Transparent*)? There is not need to remove it in post. Also it looks like you've disable the use of nodes for your white material.

Comment: Thanks! A directly transparent image was what I needed in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blue background is not just a paper that is blue. It basically means that the scene is filled with blue light thus your object seems blue.

You can set a transparent background from Render Properties panel under Film from the Transparent checkbox.

[image: Transparent background]